# php,html,js IDE

Tags: php, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smallest IDE for PHP with code-completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604608/smallest-ide-for-php-with-code-completion)

Can anyone give me link to download php IDE.

It should be specific forphp , HTML and javascript. i don't want big IDE like Dreamviewer,eclipse. any small IDE. which can run on my system configuration

```
OS : windows XP
RAM : 256 MB
```

I want to see design mode also.

Comment: Thats one ancient computer :)

Comment: Numerous duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+IDE they are not focused on a 256 MB machine but you should be able to find hints on light-weight products anyway.

Comment: I wonder, is it running in a Virtual machine ? Because otherwise, that is indeed quite an ancient machine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans has a good PHP IDE, although I haven't tried I assume it won't run on your system. You could consider using a good text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the available PHP plugins.

Comment: I don't recommend Netbeans (although I am a big Netbeans fanboy) on a system like that, Notepad++ is a good basic editor.

Comment: Can Notepad++ show design mode also ?

Answer (score 0):

And what sort of features do u want from an IDE? If you just want syntax highlighting for PHP, HTML, CSS, and Javascript, download [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).

Comment: I want to see design mode also

Answer (score 0):

Although still being developed and not fully functional, [Intype](http://intype.info) is a nice lightweight IDE similar to [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). I have been using it for few years now without problems.

Comment: Can Intype  show design mode also ?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think about is eclipse PDT http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/  is coming free.